# Export data from PDF Forms using php or in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, adobe, pdf-form

I am using Acrobat XI to collect form data and export it as csv/ xml, then I need to import it manually to mysql. Is there is any way to automate this process so I can just select/ upload the form file and data can be imported to mysql database. I know some php also and tried finding any script but not yet found. So if there is any php script to extract the data from filled pdf form that would also work for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: So you want to import CSV data automatically into database?

Comment: sorry if its unclear. I want to import data directly from pdf form to database or can get the form data in php array or something, similar to if we submit a form and get data in action file

Comment: The [SetaPDF-FormFiller](http://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-formfiller/details/) (not free!) also allows you to read PDF form field values. If you only use text fields it may also be possible to use only the [Core](http://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-core/demos/find-form-field-coordinates/) component (also not free!), too.